# Redirect citation link to custom location

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, pdfpages

I am writing a thesis with appended papers which I include using the [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package. I am using `biblatex` for referencing and `hyperref` for hyperlinks. In order to refer to the papers in the thesis, each paper has an entry in a bib-file with a `shorthand` field (Paper I, Paper II, etc.). For each `\cite` command, the shorthand is printed and `hyperref` creates a link to the paper's entry in the bibliography.

However, it would be more useful if that citation link could point to the first page of the corresponding appended paper. Alternatively, since I have a divider page preceding each included pdf, the link could point to this page. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While your problem is actually quite clear it would still help some people (me at least) if you could provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). It would be very useful to know which bibliography style you use and how you tell `biblatex` which papers will be found in the appendix.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I'll see if I can make an MWE. However, `biblatex`is completely unaware of the appendix. The paper numbers in the `shorthand` field have simply been matched to the order of the papers in the appendix. So I was looking for some way to override the link target for the `\cite` command, but only for the appended papers. The more I think about it, the simpler approach is probably to define some new command that just prints "Paper X" and links to the correct paper in the appendix. I don't really _need_ to `\cite` these papers. Edit: bibliography style is authoryear-comp.

Comment: This new command seems to be working: `\newcommand{\cpap}[1]{\hyperref[pap:#1]{\begin{NoHyper}\cite{#1}\end{NoHyper}}}`. A `label{pap:bibkey}` is put where my paper is included.  Do you see any pitfalls with this...?

Comment: Of course this requires you to know you are citing one of the special papers beforehand, but otherwise it's fine, I guess. If you think that is a valid option (I would agree) you might want to post a self-answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, but that's fine for my use. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, one may define a new command that replaces the link target of the `\cite` command:

`\newcommand{\cpap}[1]{\hyperref[pap:#1]{\begin{NoHyper}\cite{#1}\end{NoHyper}}}‌​`

A `\label{pap:citationkey}` is put at the location where you want the updated link to point, or could be defined using the (experimental) `addtotoc` command of the [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package.